Small Excel business drying up, I only know VBA, feeling quite lost
I am self-employed Excel programmer and VBA has my bread and butter for a decade or so. Lately it has started to feel that my business is slowly dying. Business calls are becoming ever rarer and while this one man show has never been a gold mine, it has afforded modest living for our family of five. Now, even though we live quite frugally, expenses have started to exceed my income and we have been digging into our small savings.
This trend has been going on for a while. Professionally I feel so... lost. There is no joy left, when there are so few customers. Just constant anxiety.
I have started to wonder what kind paths I could consider. I can code VBA and make business tools in Excel, but that is it. I do not know other languages. I can roughly understand what is probably going on if I look at a Java or Python function, but I only have cursory studies in them. Currently, I can not produce viable code in anything but VBA.
I am close to 40, so there is still time in my professional career. I hope to keep on being self-employed if possible and work from home. I am not hoping to become rich, just to earn enough to make ends meet. I am hoping to figure out a path that does not take years to pursue and in which I could somehow adapt my knowledge of VBA programming. I am hoping to avoid stepping into dying languages that have very little or very niche business utility. I am not the fastest language-learner, but I am willing to study.
Any advice is welcome, since I am quite unsure where to go from here. I am not looking for a magic bullet that solves everything, just some possible paths of least resistance. Thanks.

https://www.ziprecruiter.com/Jobs/Vba-Programmer

If you are familiar with Excel - have you looked into learning BI, PowerBI and going that route

Been through a similar situation, feel for you buddy.  I ended up taking a menial job while putting myself through uni to start fresh, I was mid 30's when I went through it and graduated in my early 40's.  Hard to do at the time but worth it in the long run.  Good luck.

VBA will become an optional component this year, it won’t be installed by default, within 4 years. Within a decade you won’t be able to enable VBA. I suspect Excel will drop support for VBA macros within 5 years. VBA is very much a dying language.

Oh wow, I really need to start paying attention to news! You are right @Donald. I just went and read the MS blog post about that. Man, they really are going to kill it and it is going to happen so soon. Only a few years left...
Yeah, I can not delay this a day longer. I am going to follow Xavier J's advice and go learn C#. Hopefully that will not end up next on the chopping block. And thanks for encouragement @solarflare! Uni is not an option for me but remote course sure are. Thanks everyone!

You have valuable skills and while you may have to pivot to working for a company instead of yourself you can still make a handsome living.

python is not difficult to learn, and you have libraries there that could do a lot of valuable things. pandas is a library to deal with tabular data, like excel, numpy is used to do operations with vectors and matrices, then you can use matplotlib to create nice plots and reportlab to create pdf reports. This are libraries worth learning to use and will give you a nice boost in your skills.

VBA will not go away, period. There are way too many large companies that have legacy macros written. The scare news is similar to that about COBOL which still hangs in there. However, there will be far more work available in python and C#.

@DavidR - Microsoft has literally said otherwise, they have even set the date, when it won’t be enabled by default. VBA absolutely is going away, I expect it to be permanently gone, approximately 2034. That’s based on a 10 year plan to sunset it.

@Donald The only notice from Microsoft I could find was about "VB script" which is a scripting language at the operating system level. They also are disabling VBA by default in Word files pulled from the internet which is a security enhancement. But VBA going away? Not going to happen no matter what the language purists want. I have heard 10 year plans for getting rid of VB for the last 20 years. VB6 is still being used and new development gigs posted on freelancer sites.

Those who think that VBA is going away don't understand how corporations operate. The first release without VBA will be met by the CEO of a 100,000 workstation company telling his MS sales rep. that they won't upgrade. That salesperson will scream to MS about it and VBA will suddenly show up again in the release.

Your most viable jumping-off place would be Visual Basic .NET.  It's still used in some legacy systems, and will be the most familiar to you.  But don't get comfy there -- make plans to switch to C#.  You can still develop your Excel stuff with either of these, but C# will bring you to the most up and current paradigm.
With either of these, you can build:

Office plugins
Console applications
Web applications
Windows applications
Mobile applications (these are much more work)

You should also learn at least one database (RDBMS), and SQL Server (start with Developer or Express) being your best shot at making some money, and then Oracle or MySQL.
Your age has nothing to do with either of these.  How bad do you want to switch?
Visual Studio Community version is FREE.  Look that up.

I like the idea of developing applications for Windows environment, since that is what I have spent my life in. Concerning typical development times, is it possible to develop affordable products with C# and SQL Server for small and medium sized businesses? Or are development times with those meant for larger enterprise clients only? Most of my clients have been on the smaller side so far, and with VBA I have been able to provide for those needs.
I am going to heed your advice though and look for courses in C# and SQL Server. Those do sound like future-proof choices.

@Caduseus I've developed quite a bunch for small businesses in C# and SQL. Many small businesses need enterprise level work and will pay for that. The cost can be similar to VBA.  However, you can add levels of protection that are not available to VBA.

@Caduseus As far as developing against a database, most small businesses won't be able to afford to use SQL Server.  MySQL cloud based hosting is cheap, on the other hand.  If you develop using an object relational mapping layer (ORM) such as Entity Framework or Fluent NHibernate, you can support whatever database platform your customers can afford.  Entity Framework is widely used for SQL Server-only development.  Fluent NHibernate, in my experience, is more seamless than Entity Framework for interoperability across databases.  YMMV

Hmm. I do not have the capacity to learn everything right away, so I have to pick and choose carefully what I commit to. If MySQL is cheaper for clients then that might be the better option to learn first. And I think I will start with Entity Framework, since that seems to be in the Microsoft ecosystem. I have no idea what it does yet, but I will get a book and start studying it as well. Thanks a lot @XavierJ for helping me find a path forward! Now I have a rough idea of what to aim for :)

@Caduseus I would personally recommend that you first introduce yourself to C# and Object Oriented Programming before diving into EntityFramework. Also familiarize yourself with LINQ enough to know what you CAN do.


Business calls are becoming ever rarer

This means it's time to do some marketing & networking. I was self employed for a long time. Businesses came looking for me, referred me to others and it was all gravy. Eventually the work dried up, there was nothing wrong with my services I'd just filled that markets potential and things were slow.
So I went looking for new customers, I didn't hope some would look for me as I have a family to feed. After I found a couple, the referrals started again and I had a new market to tap.

If there is one thing in this world I am really poor with, it is networking... My clients are almost all one and done deals and I think I have only heard once that someone contacted me through a referral.
I have only been able to work part time due to... reasons I don't need to disclose here. But I think you're right: I will have to start dedicating more time for searching potential clients to pay the bills. Even more, I have to follow Xavier J's advice and start learning C#. I don't want to get left behind and unemployable with just VBA in my skill-set.

Easier to sell yourself as an experienced expert in your field than start again in another with nothing to back you up. As a self employed anyway. You just need customers. Next time focus on networking as you go. It's easy, you don't have to kiss any butts, just come across as pleasant, professional and willing to do a bit extra. Take care of the details, stay well within timeframes etc,. basic stuff (that no-one does these days).


I am close to 40, so there is still time in my professional career

Typically speaking, a professional career doesn't even reach the peak until your 40s, and you probably have 30 years of working left.
I'm fairly proficient myself with VBA but I find it hardly ever gets used these days. In Excel, most things which once demanded VBA have been taken over by more powerful formulas, more powerful GUI functions, by Power Query and Power Pivot, and by direct access to database engines using SQL.
I would recommend learning SQL in general, as there is commonality in the language across a great many vendors, most businesses use it somewhat, and there is therefore widespread market demand.
If you are generally writing small Windows desktop applications (or maybe somewhat large ones, if you were using VBA inside Access), then learning .Net (and using Winforms there) is the best analogy to VBA, although I've personally stopped developing in Visual Studio as there is just so much clutter and overhead now that you have to be a full-timer in it just to withstand keeping your tools in order with it.
Beyond this, the technology landscape nowadays has become so balkanised that it's difficult to recommend any particular technology unless you already have a footing in it, or are drawn by your own personal preference or knowledge of local opportunities.
Unless you're an absolute whizz, then starting anything completely fresh in middle age (especially when you have a home and family to look after, and are already feeling the strain of poverty) is probably not a good idea when you'll be competing against younger workers with some capability already under their belts.
Instead you want to reuse the knowledge you already have as much as possible, or find a job that uses some of your existing skill whilst also giving you time and context to develop another skill (and ideally bringing you into contact with someone who already has the skill you want to acquire).

I really like SQL and hopefully you can find a career.  Becoming a DBA usually would require a lot of expensive training and certifications.  However, if you add SQL to the following:  C# and some HTML, you can be a multi-tier "full stack" developer and then the jobs will likely come.  Best wishes!

@JosephDoggie, I'm the person answering, not the OP. I already have a non-VBA job - I just happen also to know VBA!

Hopefully OP will see it!

See also:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402984/dislike-comments-can-only-be-edited-for-5-minutes-rule

Those are good thoughts. Yeah, it would not be easy if I had to compete against fresh graduates for a job. I am mostly looking for viable options to stay self-employed as much as possible, since it is more my jam. Even if it offers me lower income. And if my software ventures ultimately fail, I am not too proud to go drive a delivery truck :)

@Caduseus fresh graduates can't bring the business knowledge that you have nor the experience of what not to do. Don't compete with them. Aim your communications to the CEO of the company and sell that you solve business problems, not do coding in X language.

@DavidR Thanks for all the encouraging words you gave in this discussion, on multiple threads! I am going to try to balance things around the upcoming C# and MyQSL studies, since those feel like the path forward. With those under my belt and the experience I have, I think things will be alright. Unless, of course, AI comes in and steals all the programming jobs... but until then, I'll just keep on truckin'.

@Caduseus, given your Microsoft development background and continued orientation, it would make more sense to learn MS SQL Server. I noticed someone above mentioning the cost, but the Express version is free, and SSMS (also free) is the Rolls Royce of database management tools if you're running Windows.
